# Capturing by value in recursive lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, lambda

We can define recursive lambda function like

```
std::function<void(int)> fun = [&fun](int a) {  if (a) fun(a - 1); };
```

then we can call it with

```
fun(10);
```

However if I change the definition to

```
std::function<void(int)> fun = [fun](int a) {  if (a) fun(a - 1); };
```

and then try it to call with

```
fun(10);
```

segmentation fault occurs.

Can someone explain about why capture by reference works while capture by value gives segmentation fault.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Capture by value is evaluated as part of evaluating the lambda expression. At that time, `fun` is still uninitialised, because you're still evaluating its initialiser. Only after that is `fun` initialised, but by that time the copy has already happened.

The net effect is that the lambda function object stored inside `fun` has a data member named `fun` which is a copy of an uninitalised `std::function` — Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::function` for a recursive lambda isn't a good plan.  In your case, you get an uninitialized copy of the function prior to it having the lambda within it.

Which seems bad.  Undefined behavior crashes when you are lucky.

**Recursive Lambdas**

Let's say we wish to write Euclid's `gcd()` as a lambda. As a function, it is:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

But a lambda cannot be recursive, it has no way to invoke itself. A lambda has no name and using `this` within the body of a lambda refers to a captured `this` (assuming the lambda is created in the body of a member function, otherwise it is an error). So how do we solve this problem?

#### Use `std::function`

We can have a lambda capture a reference to a not-yet constructed `std::function`:

```
std::function<int(int, int)> gcd = [&](int a, int b){
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a%b);
};
```

This works, but should be used sparingly. It's slow (we're using type erasure now instead of a direct function call), it's fragile (copying `gcd` or returning `gcd` will break since the lambda refers to the original object), and it won't work with generic lambdas.

#### Using two smart pointers:

```
auto gcd_self = std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr< std::function<int(int, int)> >>();
*gcd_self = std::make_unique<std::function<int(int, int)>>(
  [gcd_self](int a, int b){
    return b == 0 ? a : (**gcd_self)(b, a%b);
  };
};
```

This adds a lot of indirection (which is overhead), but it can be copied/returned, and all copies share state.  It does let you return the lambda, and is otherwise less fragile than the above solution.

#### Use a Y-combinator

With the help of a short utility struct, we can solve all of these problems:

```
template <class F>
struct y_combinator {
    F f; // the lambda will be stored here

    // a forwarding operator():
    template <class... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        // we pass ourselves to f, then the arguments.
        // the lambda should take the first argument as `auto&& recurse` or similar.
        return f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
// helper function that deduces the type of the lambda:
template <class F>
y_combinator<std::decay_t<F>> make_y_combinator(F&& f) {
    return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
// (Be aware that in C++17 we can do better than a `make_` function)
```

we can implement our `gcd` as:

```
auto gcd = make_y_combinator(
  [](auto&& gcd, int a, int b){
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a%b);
  }
);
```

The `y_combinator` is a concept from the lambda calculus that lets you have recursion without being able to name yourself until you are defined.  This is exactly the problem lambdas have.

You create a lambda that takes "recurse" as its first argument.  When you want to recurse, you pass the arguments to recurse.

The `y_combinator` then returns a function object that calls that function with its arguments, but with a suitable "recurse" object (namely the `y_combinator` itself) as its first argument.  It forwards the rest of the arguments you call the `y_combinator` with to the lambda as well.

In short:

```
auto foo = make_y_combinator( [&](auto&& recurse, some arguments) {
  // write body that processes some arguments
  // when you want to recurse, call recurse(some other arguments)
});
```

and you have recursion in a lambda with no serious restrictions or significant overhead.

Part of this answer (The Recursive Lambda) was originally written by [@Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) on the defunct Stack Overflow Documentation.

Comment: Or don't use a lambda — use a class or function.

Comment: For the y-combinator I had to specify the return value of the lambda to get it to compile: `[](auto&& gcd, int a, int b) -> int`.